# Crash on + (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data scale:(CGFloat)scale on iOS 8 | EXC_BAD_ACCESS UNKNOWN or KERNEL_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata, exc-bad-access

The top 2 crash of my app happens on the method below:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data scale:(CGFloat)scale
```

So far it has occurred more than 2000 times and it manifest itself in slightly different ways according to the crash reports:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000004
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  ImageIO                        0x27b6a1b6 CGImagePlusSetImageBlockProc + 41
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x34a5139b calloc + 58
2  ImageIO                        0x27b671c5 initImagePng + 4492
3  ImageIO                        0x27b65a2f makeImagePlus + 930
4  ImageIO                        0x27b65271 CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex + 160
5  UIKit                          0x2a1e0bf3 _UIImageRefFromData + 262
6  UIKit                          0x2a32d191 -[UIImage(UIImagePrivate) _initWithData:preserveScale:cache:] + 76
7  UIKit                          0x2a1e0ae5 -[UIImage initWithData:] + 28
8  UIKit                          0x2a2a36af -[UIImage initWithData:scale:] + 22
9  UIKit                          0x2a32b721 +[UIImage imageWithData:scale:] + 56

EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreFoundation                 0x25bca41c CFArrayGetCount + 23
1  ImageIO                        0x26c3898b getImagePlus + 118
2  ImageIO                        0x26c3898b getImagePlus + 118
3  ImageIO                        0x26c38433 makeImagePlus + 46
4  ImageIO                        0x26c37fed CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex + 160
5  UIKit                          0x292954c3 _UIImageRefFromData + 282
6  UIKit                          0x293e1ad9 -[UIImage(UIImagePrivate) _initWithData:preserveScale:cache:] + 76
7  UIKit                          0x292953a5 -[UIImage initWithData:] + 28
8  UIKit                          0x29357ee7 -[UIImage initWithData:scale:] + 22
9  UIKit                          0x293e0081 +[UIImage imageWithData:scale:] + 56 

EXC_BAD_ACCESS UNKNOWN at 0x0000000104f44000
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x0000000194795390 _platform_memmove + 320
1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000194690424 __memcpy_chk + 32
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000194690424 __memcpy_chk + 32
3  ImageIO                        0x0000000184a3172c _CGImageSourceBindToPlugin + 316
4  ImageIO                        0x0000000184a31574 CGImageSourceGetCount + 112
5  UIKit                          0x000000018816d46c _UIImageRefFromData + 276
6  UIKit                          0x00000001882d1c20 -[UIImage(UIImagePrivate) _initWithData:preserveScale:cache:] + 112
7  UIKit                          0x000000018823e21c -[UIImage initWithData:scale:] + 32
8  UIKit                          0x00000001882cffa4 +[UIImage imageWithData:scale:] + 72
```

I don't see how my code could affect this but I tried sending nil to this method and it just returns nil. Would a corrupted NSData be able to cause this crash? Does this method retain the NSData? Would it be cause by the NSData being released while this line is processing? I don't think so because it's synchronous, right?

Besides that, I couldn't reproduce this bug but since we have a big user base it happens often. I also noted it happens 99% of the times on iOS 8.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I also posted this question on Apple Developer Forums in case you want to follow: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/264224?tstart=0

Answer (score 3):

Are you using a library as AFNetwork or Hanekee? I've just submitted a pull request to both this libraries because of ios8 UIImage imageWithData. It seems UIImage with data is NOT thread safe, meaning that calling it simultaneous from different threads it will crash.... A way to replicate this is to test the following code:

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTf4P0V2TrszykwPguyeulcSt4vwQPcvvWKKq_RePhUUVFoHevG9lw8GVcw")!)
    var test: Array<UIImage> = []
    let lock = NSLock()
    for i in 0...10000 {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
            NSLog("Processing \(i)")
            let a = UIImage(data:data!)
            NSLog("Processed \(i)")
            lock.lock()
            test.append(a!)
            test.removeLast()
            lock.unlock()
        })
```

So make sure you synchronise UIImage(data:data!) or [UIImage imageWithData:data] calls to avoid simultaneous calls.

Pull Requests:

Haneke: https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift/pull/207

AFNetwork: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/2815

Comment: Yes I'm using AFNetworking. I'll investigate this, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, actually in my case, I am using `imageWithData:` in multiple locations, so I believe a better solution is to make a category on UIImage with a method `safe_imageWithData:` that synchronizes all usage across the app .. Even though I say this, sounds ridiculous to have such a bug in UIKit, how can we be certain non of the system frameworks nor third party libs are using this method? __Sounds like a perfect usage of swizzling__

Comment: Yes category is probably the best way to go here... Just filed a bug report to apple 21587881 lets see if they fix it... they do have a note on the docs stating "For the most part, use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way." Don't think this applies to this specific case though...